# Можно ли настроить выдачу страницы по заданному адресу?

Tags: windows, сервер, proxy

Например, я ввожу адрес сайта, но попадаю не на него, а на сохраненную страничку на локальном компьютере. Проблема в том, что веб сервера нету и прокси настроить тоже нет возможности. Так что может быть какая-нибудь простенькая программа есть, реализующая такую возможность, или ещё что нибудь?

Comment: Кажется, без локального веб сервера тут не обойтись.

Comment: "Мы не ищем лёгких путей", это про вас.

Answer (score 1):

1. Так делает кэш браузера, например Opera.
2. Если вы в Windows есть файл hosts в `System32\drivers\etc`.
3. Это изврат, но можно установить прокси прямо на эту машину, например Squid по порту например 8080 и туда цеплять браузер.

Comment: а можно поподробнее как это делает кэш брауера? можно ли его вручную изменить и чтобы он впоследствии не очищался?
при чём тут hosts? не думаю что он сможет помочь чем то.
сказал же что прокси не вариант, тем более что сами видите что это изврат